# SwiftUI - conditional Text

Tags: swiftui

I'm trying to use a Text label to output a string based on a UserDefault setting for what the translation they prefer:

```
Text(settings.translation? tangoArray[self.id].romaji : tangoArray[self.id].hiragana)
```

Is there any reason why the above line of code doesn't work, and what small modification do I need to make?

Comment: is the `setting` connected in a view hierarchy

Comment: it's in my ContentView.

class UserSettings: ObservableObject {
    @Published var translation = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "Translation")
}

Comment: please provide a simple example.

Answer (score 2):

If the `translation` is defined as (and hopefully changed somewhere as well)

```
class UserSettings: ObservableObject {
    @Published var translation = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "Translation")
}
```

... then it has `Int` type, but in `Text` you must have `Bool`, so it should be like

```
Text(settings.translation == _romaji_int_code_ ? 
    tangoArray[self.id].romaji : tangoArray[self.id].hiragana)
```

Comment: Thanks, that works! If I were to expand to this a third option "both (romaji and hiragana)", how would I do it?

Comment: Not sure I understood what do you mean... how are you going to store 'both' translation values under one key? and what would that act for?

Comment: Say in my database I have a third column that is a concatenation of the first two. I want to offer this option to my users if they want to see both romaji and hiragana. So I'm almost writing a switch statement inside the Text, but that doesn't seem elegant does it?

Comment: It depend... on ui design, on requirement to extendability... it is possible to do with `if`, with `switch`, extract it into separated view builder... in short, depends... elegant is not always a criteria, as for me... but that's different question. ))